# 2002 Chevrolet Tracker Brake Lights on dash are going on and off

Tags: chevrolet, tracker

I have a 2002 Chevy Tracker w/ approx. 90,000 miles, 4-door & 2.5L V6 motor.  It was LITERALLY just taken from the garage where it was in for inspection/emissions and everything for the inspection was perfect....Brakes, Fluids, Etc...  After having it back for a few days I noticed the inside light flickering (coming on when I hit bumps) so I just disconnected it and I noticed the "Brake" light on the dash coming on but just on hard braking or sharp left hand turns, the next day the light wouldn't go off unless it was a hard right hand turn......my mechanic did mention I needed a new light bulb for my license plate (Which is connected to the whole back panel that opens the door, hold the plate, etc... and you can tell it's loose...can this be the problem or am I looking at something major....This one has got me stumped!!!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Sounds like your brake fluid is low. Before adding brake fluid, though, see if the pads are getting worn out (or near worn out). If not, you may have a leak in your system, which would need to be remedied.